# change javascript response and resend it

Tags: python, json, python-requests, web-crawler

I'm trying to get a java script file from a server, manipulate it and resend it as response to another request.
Here's the request and the response file

```
import requests as req
headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive',\
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',\
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',\
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
    Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',\
    'Accept': '*/*',\
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en- US;q=0.8,fa;q=0.7,eo;q=0.6',\
    'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.1.879245751.1566985641; cookieconsent_status=dismiss; \
    csrftoken=soEaxgZCM95FtydIUO4McG7G5Uek2uknLRCs0K6VI8amnbEAw1dXWV3kIONBtpgV; \
    _gid=GA1.1.1723047283.1573514239; io=yWUz84McCeIU7PLvJz1w'}
response = req.get('https://skribbl.io/js/game.js', headers = headers)
```

Now I want to edit the js file, for example, I want to add a line to first line of a function of it. 
My code is here

```
x = 'o.prototype.createTransport=function(t){'
y = 'o.prototype.createTransport=function(t){console.log(this.hostname);'
response.__dict__['_content'] = str.encode(str(response.__dict__['_content']).replace(x, y))
```

The content changes correctly but the problem is that I think I should change the 'content-length' and some other attributes which I don't know so that the browser can parse this new js code. For example, I don't know how to calculate new 'content-length' of this response. And after that is there any standard library(like beautiful soap for html files) which does this operation automatically?

Comment: Are you trying to send your request back to the server, or to inject some JavaScript code of yours into the `game.js` file you got from the server and run it in a web browser?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this. But for testing purpose you can try to use Resource Override extension for Chrome. So you will be able to change external JS file to any you want.

Comment: @Pierre Yes I want to send request back to the server

Comment: @uaBArt Thanks, but I want to do this in python and edit the response of req.get().

Comment: @kami54 Which endpoint on the server do you want to send it to?

Comment: @Pierre You can see this as a proxy server. I get a request from server A, then get this java script file from server B, change it and send it as the response to server A. I mean I want to send this manipulated js file as a response to another request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to edit the js file. JS files are consistent and don't change in time. So you download the file once, change it and save your changes. Then whenever you want to serve the file, resend the change javascript file saved in your computer.